# Pack of Emacs plugins/mods?

Tags: emacs

does anyone know where I can find a pack of plugins for Emacs ?

I'd like support for a wide range of languages? (JS, JS integrated in html(...), Xhtml, Php, Python, Cpp, etc.)

I love Emacs and it's plugins but I'm bored with ugly code (the debugger is also missing...?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah! There's got to be something like XAMPP, where you get a "good" setup in a few minutes on a fresh machine, without having to hack Lisp.

Comment: What do you mean by "the debugger is missing"? There are two of them built in. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugging.html

Comment: What OS is this for? if its on a variety linuxes your looking for the 'emacs-goodies' package.

Comment: https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d

Comment: http://emacs.vote-system.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using recent (recent means at least Emacs 24 prerelease) you can add this into your `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmelade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
```

After that, invoking `M-x package-list-packages` will bring you the buffer with a bunch of thirdparty packages you can install.

Comment: Nice thank you, but where can I find Emacs 24 for linux ? Have you a link please ?

Comment: I just grab the source and build it myself.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to check out the [Emacs Starter Kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit#readme). I think it's the most well-known attempt to avoid the need to customise Emacs yourself.

Aside from that, have a look at the various package management solutions around.

ELPA and el-get are good places to start, IMO.

[What do you expect from a package manager for Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454259/what-do-you-expect-from-a-package-manager-for-emacs)

Comment: An explanation for down-voting the two answers which suggested the Emacs Starter Kit would be appreciated. AFAIK it's quite popular, and its README file would seem to be in line with this question's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should try http://EmacsWiki.org you can find a very large number of elisp scripts/plugins there.

For color schemes, try http://inspiration.sweyla.com/code/seed/697890/?lang=ruby or http://jasonm23.github.com/

To setup debugging, it's heavily dependent on the language you want to use, for JS/HTML you are best off using a browser like Chromium, which has good debug/console features.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows there is [EmacsWin32](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/EmacsW32) which comes with several packages preloaded and ready to go.

The best way to find a good list of packages is to read other peoples `.emacs` files.  If you haven't had the joy of playing with your .emacs file yet, [Steve Yegge's is a good place to start](http://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/my-dot-emacs-file)

Answer (score 1):

The [Emacs starter kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit) is a pretty thorough beginning collection of packages. I've also recently come across [Naquadah](http://julien.danjou.info/blog/2011.html#Naquadah_theme_for_Emacs) and it's become my favorite theme.