# Is there an Emacs alternative to Pathogen from Vim?

Tags: vim, emacs

I am trying to move from Vim to Emacs and have had some "translation" issues. For example the extension or add on managing. So I was wondering if there was something like pathogen for Emacs although I am very suspicious of the fact that perhaps there isn't one because the way Emacs handles it's extensions it is not needed. I think this has been my only quirk with the editor so far. Other than that I can notice the different approaches of both tools and realize that they excel in what they are supposed to do. Thanks!

EDIT: Right. What pathogen does is manage Vim extensions by loading them as "Bundles" instead of having each file on a different folder inside your `.vim` folder. You have it centralized and autoloaded by pathogen itself.

Comment: For those in the audience who are familiar with Emacs but not with Vim, what does Pathogen do?

Comment: It's plugin which helps you organize and manage other plugins

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454259/what-do-you-expect-from-a-package-manager-for-emacs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ELPA, the Emacs Lisp Package Archive:

http://tromey.com/elpa/

Comment: And note that http://marmalade-repo.org/ is now the primary non-GNU source of packages for use with ELPA.

Comment: elpa is a package archive.

This is not in any way shape or form comparable to pathogen, which is as the OP says a vim plugin that helps you manage your vim plugins as bundles.

Answer (score 3):

From [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA),

> package.el (from ELPA) will be added
>   to vanilla GnuEmacs, version 24. As of
>   2010-06-18, package.el has been merged
>   with the development version of Emacs,
>   and an ELPA repository has been set up
>   at http://elpa.gnu.org/.

[el-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get) is another option.